# Menus in navigation bar not showing in mobile view

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a resposive site which works fine on desktop but not in mobile and Tablet view. Navbars are shown in Tablet and Mobile view but the menus are not shown.

This is my website: http://www.sociolife.co.in/

I am using this as my sample template: http://dynamicmag-sbtemplates.blogspot.in/ and here menus in navbar are showing properly in mobile view. I want menus in navbar should look exactly like the sample template

Can you please help me to fix it out. The menus in navbar should be exactly like the sample template whose link I have given here.

Comment: This is what happening: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/866bi2l7oho5w6y/prob1.JPG

Comment: Did you use bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your desktop nav code. If this answers your question please vote. thanks

```
  <ul class="menu l_tinynav1" id="menu-main">
  <li><!-- Your Desktop Nav Code --></li>
<script type="text/javascript">ndom'; 
  </script>
</ul><!-- here onwards you add the code I mentioned earlier.  -->
```

Comment: bro is working fine.... but after adding those lines of code, if u open my site in mobile, it will be showing like this: screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/7ysrysxolcwf6jc/snapshots10641240_879586612108550_6197319113253953472_n.jpg                now in mobile its showing 2 menus.

Comment: I just tested your site. It seems to be working fine. here is screeshot. http://snag.gy/vgy3r.jpg and here is while clicking on the menu http://snag.gy/I4EVB.jpg and here is a real time mobile version http://snag.gy/qmLYe.jpg

Comment: It seems you have two select code. <select class="tinynav"></select> and the other is<select class="tinynav tinynav1" id="tinynav1">
</select> remove one of those select or use "display:none" CSS . Please vote if  I answered your question. thanks.

Comment: bro where is the other select code? i cannot find it in my template

Comment: You have two url. Your desktop URL  http://www.sociolife.co.in/ and your mobile url  http://www.sociolife.co.in/?m=1 . Two Select is loading from your Mobile URL content.

Comment: i cannot understand where i have to make changes again :(

Comment: I am sorry, I wont be able to help you personally in your blog. You will need to provide a  proper code and your directory structure. Edit your Question, that way it will get regenerated in stackoverflow questions.

Comment: bro here is the xml template code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qxja1zyd62hmb8l/template-1527028288287183380.xml?dl=0         please check it out and see where i can make changes

Comment: your site is not meant to have select option according to its core feature and layout. which means there is no dropdown menu in mobile version.  check this out. http://dynamicmag-sbtemplates.blogspot.in/?m=1 . You will therefore need to hard code customize the core framework or change your redirect url so that it does not get redirected to ?m=1. but then this will change your Mobile layout.

Comment: bro so what all changes i have to make then because in sample template in mobile view i can see those menus in navbar.... so what should I bro. thanks in advance

Comment: bro please tell me at what place and where i should change the code

Comment: do you see the sample template menu nav bar in your "MOBILE PHONE" browser? The mobile view in rendering depending not according to width of the browser but type of browser, desktop or mobile. You need to check in your mobile phone browser.

Comment: yeah bro i have seen it. ok that means whatever menu nav bar i will see in my mobile phone browser i will also see the same in my tablet web browser?

Comment: have you removed the select options already? Because I tested on my mobile phone. The drop down menu is working perfectly fine now. click on this link and decrease your browser width. http://www.sociolife.co.in/?m=1

Comment: yes bro i removed the select option.... and thiis one: http://www.sociolife.co.in/?m=1 working perfectly when decreasing width. But what about desktop version: http://www.sociolife.co.in/ how we will fix the menu navbar  while decreasing width. Should i make nabar display: none; when desktop browser < 1028 px so that it wont show navbar and there will be nor problem for menus or will u provide another better soln.?

Comment: You are getting confused. You do not need to decrease your browser width in our desktop. You website uses two url. if Your browser is desktop your url is  sociolife.co.in and for mobile web browser it reidrects to  sociolife.co.in/?m=1 . Your site is perfectly fine. No need to make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this select line of code.

```
      <select id="tinynav1" class="tinynav tinynav1">  <option>Navigation</option>      <option value="/">Home</option><option value="your-link-here">Business</option><option value="your-link-here">- Post With Featured Image</option><option value="your-link-here">- Post With Slider</option><option value="your-link-here">- Post with SoundCloud</option><option value="your-link-here">- Post With Video</option><option value="your-link-here">Technology</option><option value="your-link-here">- Authors</option><option value="your-link-here">- Sitemap</option><option value="your-link-here">- Tags</option><option value="your-link-here">- Timeline</option><option value="your-link-here">Life &amp; Style</option><option value="your-link-here">Games</option><option value="your-link-here">- Full Width</option><option value="your-link-here">- Right Sidebar</option><option value="your-link-here">- Left SIdebar</option><option value="your-link-here">Sports</option><option value="your-link-here">- Stars</option><option value="your-link-here">- Points</option><option value="your-link-here">- Percent</option><option value="your-link-here">- in The Top</option><option value="your-link-here">Error Page</option><option value="#random"></option></select>
```

Comment: i have removed this code still its creating problem because navbar is moving towards right. its better pleae you check the sample template and see how the menus in navbar are working in that template

Comment: Sir i checked ur answer but where should I add this line? its better i add you in my blogger account so you make the necessary changes. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some code (select). They are hidding "ul" and showing "select" when it comes to mobile..

Add this below your ul#menu-main tag

like this:

```
<ul id="menu-main">something</ul> // add under this ul tag

<select id="tinynav1" class="tinynav tinynav1">
 <option>Navigation</option><option value="/">Home</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">Business</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- Post With Featured Image</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- Post With Slider</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- Post with SoundCloud</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- Post With Video</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">Technology</option><option value="your-link-here">- Authors</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- Sitemap</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- Tags</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- Timeline</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">Life &amp; Style</option><option value="your-link-here">Games</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- Full Width</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- Right Sidebar</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- Left SIdebar</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">Sports</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- Stars</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- Points</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- Percent</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">- in The Top</option>
 <option value="your-link-here">Error Page</option>
 <option value="#random"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try this it will work, Add it at specified place @Dianara Fernandez Pakingor

Comment: bro is working fine.... but after adding those lines of code, if u open my site in mobile, it will be showing like this: screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/7ysrysxolcwf6jc/snapshots10641240_879586612108550_6197319113253953472_n.jpg                now in mobile its showing 2 menus.

Comment: Its working fine for me in chrome when i set iphone 6 as my device. please post the code you added or try in chrome like this. open chrome -> open your site -> press f12 -> click mobile icon from the top of DOM. -> set iphone 6 or any device u needed and refresh it.

Comment: @DianaraFernandezPakingor you have added the select statement twice in your project. please remove the second one and run it.

Comment: @DianaraFernandezPakingor You have added select twice                                  <select class="tinynav"></select>
<select class="tinynav tinynav1" id="tinynav1"></select>        In this remove the second one from the your project.

Comment: @DianaraFernandezPakingor Please can you select my answer to appreciate my help. Thanks.